# Getting exif data from php

Tags: php, exif

Hi again I'm trying to get a good exif parser for files.
So far I'm using Exif reader v 1.2
But I'm have some trouble reading the lens information i.e what it was taken by. Does anyone have any good solutions.
Thanks 
Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using the PHP function [`exif_read_data()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) ?

EDIT: Here are some others libs (all of them look unmaintained) :

- ZenPhoto exit component : http://www.zenphoto.org/trac/browser/trunk/zp-core/exif
- PHP JPEG Metadata toolkit : http://www.ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/index.html
- PEL: PHP Exif Library http://pel.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the links I've been trying them out. But none of the seem to get the lens information. Is this even possible?