# Get EXIF data from videos in php

Tags: php, video, exif

What's the easiest way to extract the datetime captured timestamp from a video recorded with a Canon camera?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting exif data from php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319803/getting-exif-data-from-php)

Comment: Not a dup.  Other question was for still images.  I don't think it's called exif for video.

Comment: Hi -- My camera doesn't store .THM sidecar files, unfortunately.  Is there a way to read directly from the video file?

Comment: have you tried any of the suggestions in the linked question's answers yet?