# extract info from jpeg with PHP

Tags: php, jpeg

I want to extract variable lengths of information from a jpeg-file using PHP, but it is **not** exif-data.

If I open the jpeg with a simple text editor, I can see that the wanted informations are at the end of the file and seperated by `\00`.

Like this:

```
\00DATA\00DATA00DATA\00DATA\000\00DATA
```

Now if I use PHP's `file_get_contents()` to load the file into a string, the dividers `\00` are gone and other symbols show up. 
Like so:

```
ÿëžDATADATADATADATADATA ÿÙ
```

Could somebody please eplain:

- Why do the `\00` dividers vanish?
- How to get the informations using PHP?

**EDIT**

The question is solved, but for those seeking a smarter solution, here is the file I try to obtain the DATA parts from: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5cwnlh2kadvi6f7/test-img.jpg?dl=0  (yes I know its corrupted)

Comment: can you upload the image?

Comment: I am sorry, I can not, but there is no need to. The question is already solved and I am going to accept the Answer once SO lets me.

Comment: yes i see but was interested to find a smarter solution :)

Comment: If somebody comes up with a smarter solution, I will accept their answer of course.

Comment: ... but without the image it is not possible ;)

Comment: Well, I can not upload the image because SO tells me its corrupted (which I know it is). I will add a link to download the file. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution on my own. May not be pretty, but works for me.

Using `urlencode(file_get_contents())` I was able to retrieve the `\00` parts as `%00`.

So now it reads like this:

```
%00DATA%00DATA%00DATA%00DATA%000%00DATA
```

I can split the string at the `%00` parts.

**I am going to accept this answer, once SO lets me do so and nobody comes up with a better solution.**

Answer (score 1):

Use instead `$data = exif_read_data("PATH/some.jpg")` it will give you all headers data about image, you can check its manual here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: I already tried that. It provides some other information, like height and length, but not the informations I need. So the infos are not exif-data.

Comment: in your question problem with `\00` i guess related to encoding you need to find correct encoding, but anyway i will suggest you to try use something ready made E.G.  check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319803/getting-exif-data-from-php first answer, there suggested other php image reader libs

Comment: yeah, I think you are right about the encoding-problem. I tried using the libs provided, but most can not be installed due to various reasons regarding a lack of maintenance, or they can still not find the informations needed.